# Does every sequence of Real Numbers have a subsequence of rational numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence that does not converge, and let $M$ be a real number. I am thinking about how to show that there exists a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ that converges to $M$. If I could show that there is a rational subsequence, then could I use the fact that every real number is the limit of a convergent sequence of rational numbers?

Comment: $x_n=n\pi$ is a sequence of real numbers that does not converge.  It has no convergent subsequences of rational numbers, and no subsequences that converge to anything (except infinity).

Answer (score 1):

Not every sequence has a rational subsequence.  For example, the sequence given by
$$
x_n = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}
$$
is a convergent sequence of *irrrational* numbers.

Comment: How then would I show that if ${x_n}$  be a sequence of reals that does not converge, there exists a subsequence of ${x_n}$ that converges to M?

Comment: You don’t, because that isn’t a true statement, unless you are given more information (for example, the sequence is bounded)

Answer (score 0):

There are sequences of real numbers without a subsequence of rational numbers. Choose $x_{2n-1} = \sqrt{2}$ and $x_{2n} = \sqrt{3}$. You can't show that this has a subsequence converging to $M = 0$ because it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Sequence:

$x_n =\sqrt {p_n}$, where $p_n$ are the primes enumerated.

Is there a rational subsequence ?